# Bootstrap 2 Modal .removeData

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2, jquery-gmap3

I have a map script using the gmap3 plugin and am sorting out how to implement a modal when a marker is clicked on. Everything is working ok except the when I click on a new marker, my script is loading the string from the previous markers clicked. I placed .removeData in the script, but it does not seem to be working.

here is the script:

```
<script>
$('#map_canvas').gmap3({
  map:{
    options:{ 
      streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      },
    }
  },
  marker:{
    values:[
        <!-- TMPL_LOOP Listings -->
            <!-- TMPL_IF have_geocode -->
                {latLng:[<!-- TMPL_VAR latitude -->, <!-- TMPL_VAR longitude -->],data:'<div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a href="/property/detail/<!-- TMPL_VAR listing_id -->" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" target="_self">View Details</a></div>',options:{icon: "/static/images/mapmarker.png"}},
            <!-- TMPL_ELSE -->
                {address:"<!-- TMPL_VAR street_no --> <!-- TMPL_VAR street -->, <!-- TMPL_VAR city -->, <!-- TMPL_VAR state --> <!-- TMPL_VAR zip -->",data:'<div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a href="/property/detail/<!-- TMPL_VAR listing_id -->" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" target="_self">View Details</a></div>',options:{icon: "/static/images/mapmarker.png"}},
            <!-- /TMPL_IF -->
        <!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
    ],
    options:{
      draggable: false
    },
    events:{
        click: function(marker, event, context){
            $('#mapModal').on('hidden', function() {
                $(this).removeData('modal');
            });
            $('#mapModal').append('<div class="modal-body"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+(context.data)+'</div>');
            $('#mapModal').modal('show')
            $(this).gmap3('get').panTo(marker.getPosition());
        },
    },
  },
  autofit:{},
});
```

and the modal container:

```
<div id="mapModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mapModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$('#mapModal').empty();
```